# How to develop a wordpress site in the root while a static site exists?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, root

Can I have an index2.php file and redirect the htacess file for the meantime?  If so how do I redirect the page for the time being so I can change it later?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

## Put WordPress somewhere else

This is, by far, the easiest way to create a WordPress site while keeping an existing site active.

1. Install WordPress in a *different* location than your existing, static site
2. [Edit your Windows `.hosts` file](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/hosts-file-configuration-windows-linux-and-mac/) so that your computer points to the new location when you try browsing to the existing site
3. Set up WordPress and get your site up-and-running
4. When you're ready to go, tell your server to redirect requests from the old location to the new location

This is similar to the process I use when setting up a new site or working on a client system.  If my static site is `http://mysite.com/` and lives on `/public_html/mysite.com/` on the server, I'll park WordPress in `/public_html/wordpress/` and create a subdomain that points there (`http://beta.mysite.com/`).  When everything is ready, I just change my DNS settings and everything moves automatically.

## Set up your default documents in `.htaccess`

If your existing site is static, it's probably got an `index.html` file in the root.  You can [tell your `.htaccess` file to use this as the default document](http://www.blog.highub.com/apache/http-server/htaccess-explicitly-define-default-index-file/).  Then, regular requests to your site will go to the static site, but you can manually go to WordPress by placing `index.php` at the end of your URL.

The big lesson to learn here, though, is that you should ***never*** develop on a production site.  You should develop your WordPress site somewhere else (locally on your computer, on a subdomain, in a subfolder, etc) and only move it to the root of your live site when you're ready for it to go public.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to install in a subdirectory like /dev/ and protect the site with a plugin like [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) and then when it's ready, move it to root: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) No need for redirects or vhosts editing.